# How to get the changed date from bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using [Eternicode's fork of the bootstrap-datepicker library](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) and until now all is going well for generating it, but I want to get the date in order to use it in my logic after changing the date.

```
$('#calendar').on('changeDate', function(event, date) {
  // how to pop alert message to print the date I've chosen ?
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As [described in the docs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html), the Eternicode version of bootstrap-datepicker adds three attributes to the `changeDate` event that can be used for accessing the newly selected date. You'll be interested in either the `.date` property (which points to the actual [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) representing the selected date) or the `.format` method, which you can use to get the date as a string.

Assuming the simplest case (where you have a single picker and you want to get the date as a string in the same format that you initialised the datepicker with), you'll just want to call `.format()` with no arguments:

```
$('#calendar').on('changeDate', function(event) {
    alert(event.format());
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle showing this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/bhm7p/3/

Comment: Actually your fiddle contains different code. It calls .datepicker() before .on() - this is essential.

Comment: @buffjape well, sure - if you don't call `.datepicker()` at some point in the code, then you don't have a datepicker. But note that the `.datepicker()` call just returns the jQuery collection it was called on for chaining, not any kind of special datepicker object - so you don't need to call `.on()` specifically on the result of the `.datepicker()` call, you just need to have called `.datepicker` somewhere in your code. See http://jsfiddle.net/bhm7p/33/ for an illustration of this.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the jquery function body:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#datepicker').on('dp.change', function(){
    var t=Date.parse($("#dob1").val());    
    if (t > Date.now()) {
      alert('Selected date shold not be a future date');
      $("#dob1").val('');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two things you could try.

Try implementing this line:

```
$('#startdate').val()
```

Or this one:

```
$('#startdate').data('date')
```

Drew T. suggests using .val() - also very efficient.

```
$('#calendar').on('changeDate', function(event, date) {
    var date = $('#calendar').val();
    alert(date);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

actually the fundamental is like this:
you will get access to the date by the `.on` event that parsed to the `e` parameter. from `e` you can't access to `.getDate`

```
$('#calendar').on('changeDate', function(e) {
    alert(e.getDate()+'/'+e.getMonth()+e.getFullYear());
});
```

if you can't understand how this happened, you can put the response in `console.log(e)` rather than `alert(e.getDate)` so you can get a clear view on what to access.